# Why are my checkboxes misaligning on mobile?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, bootstrap-4

I have a couple of checkboxes with the following markup:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-check">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input col-md-3" id="updates">
                <label class="form-check-label col-md-9 text-left" for="updates"><small>Want to receive updates.</small></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-check">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input col-md-3" id="customer">
                <label class="form-check-label col-md-9 text-left" for="customer"><small>I want to subscribe</small></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

They work just fine. The only issue is that while on desktop they look well, starting from tablet and onward they begin to push towards the middle of the field so that when they are seen in mobile, the checkbox is dead-center (under the text). Still clickable but no idea why this is happening.

I'm using bootstrap 4 and jquery 3.3.1.

Comment: How about a couple of screenshots for comparison?

Comment: try with col-xs-3; The Bootstrap grid system has four classes: xs (phones), sm (tablets), md (desktops), and lg (larger desktops)

Comment: @Lab Actually `col-xs` isn't valid for Bootstrap 4. It's just `col`.

Comment: @Lab No problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [the Bootstrap 4 Grid documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/); it looks like you may be misusing the Grid classes.

`.row`s should be the topmost element, directly followed by `.col*` elements. Then you can put `.form-group`s inside the columns; but they shouldn't contain the full `.row`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `form-group row` (a form-group-row combination) and then put the contents into a column inside.

In the following example, the classes `col-sm-10 offset-1` mean it's a column that takes up 10 units with an offset of one.

Here's a working code snippet (click the "run code snippet" button below):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form class="mt-4">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-10 offset-1">
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="updates">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="updates">
                    <small>Want to receive updates.</small>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-10 offset-1">
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="customer">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="customer">
                    <small>I want to subscribe</small>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```